# How to create a slidable sidebar using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a slidable sidebar using reactjs. But for some reasons it is not happening. The code i have written in as given below;

**Sidebar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul className="sidebar-nav">
          <li className="sidebar-brand">
            <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Overview</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Events</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Sidebar from './Components/Sidebar/Sidebar'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showResults: true
    }
    this.handleSlide = this.handleSlide.bind(this);
  }
  handleSlide() {
    this.setState({ showResults: !this.state.showResults })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="wrapper" className="toggled">
        {this.state.showResults ? <Sidebar /> : null}
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <button onClick={this.handleSlide}>
              {this.state.open ? 'Close' : 'Open'}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this code only toggles the state and by which i show or hide the sidebar div. But is it possible to create a slidable div with this. And i dont want to use any plugin that is available on the internet. So can someone help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ReactCSSTransitionGroup** which can be found in the **react-addons-css-transition-group** npm module.

Use it like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group'

class MyComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        <ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
         transitionName="slider"
         transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
         transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}
        >
          {(this.state.showResults)?<Sidebar />:null}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    }
}
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.slider-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.slider-leave {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}
```

Read more about ReactCSSTransition [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the side bar component by using css at first and and reveal it with animation on clicking. I have created a demo [here](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KtFw7OG0wrNeuNZxUc8).